# Solved: unable to get local issuer certificate in Visual Studio 2022 #111175

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

Cannot use Github Copilot in Visual Studio 2022 due to the problem of cannot get local issuer certificate

I've posted the solution in this link, please take a look

[My posted answers in Github Discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/111175)

The key point is the linke to download Zscaler has been expired since 1st February 2024, so I found another way to download it without that link: it has been installed in our laptop.

Once we downloaded it and rename to .pem, then follow the steps from Siraf's solution and everything's been solved